# cannot figure out how to remove null values from a matrix--expression is not value

Tags: reporting-services, powerbi

been a while.
I am trying to create an ssrs report
I have a matrix that is returning

[image: This is how i have it returning now]

And my filter is: [image]

See, what is happening is there are Yes, No's and '' in the data set and I can't really manipulate it.
I am just trying to get it to also display No columns.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you want to remove empty/null rows? and can you use `powerbi`, as tagged, instead of ssrs reports?

Answer (score 0):

On your tablix, use the following filter

Expression : `=Iif(Fields!Paid_under_40.Value <> "", True, False)`

Type: Boolean

Operator: =

Value = True

[image]

On my sample data one row is null and the other is empty.

The second tablix has the filter enabled.

```
select 'Yes' AS 'Paid_under_40', 77 AS 'countnum'
union all
'No', 100
union all
Null, 0
union all
'', 0
```

[image]